# How to switch flow based on condition?

Tags: kotlin, androidx, kotlin-flow, android-paging-3

There is `query` and two filters. When set `search` filter and `query` is not empty, need to one flow. When set `checked` filter need to other flow.

According debug, `onClickSearchFilter` or `onClickCheckedFilter` calls with query or filter changed - return new flow. But in UI no changes, collector dont work second time.

1. How to switch flow based on condition?
2. When I debugging with breakpoints in flows, app crash every time `A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x14 in tid 23174 (JDWP), pid 23167` . Rebuild, clear cache, reload device - dont' help.

```kotlin
repeatOnStarted(viewModel.itemsFlow) {
    // it doesn't work when flow is switched
    pagingAdapter.submitData(it)
}
```

```kotlin
val itemsFlow = queryFlow
    .debounce(1000)
    .combine(filterFlow) { query, filter ->
        when (filter) {
            R.id.search_result_chip -> onClickSearchFilter(query)
            R.id.checked_chip -> onClickCheckedFilter()
            else -> throw Exception("")
        }
    }.flatMapMerge { // in order to switch from Flow<Flow<*>> to Flow<*>
        it
    }

private fun onClickSearchFilter(query: String): Flow<PagingData<ItemEntity>> {
    return if (query.length < 2)
        emptyFlow()
    else Pager(BasePagingSource.getConfig()) {
        SearchPagingSource(query, client)
    }.flow.cachedIn(viewModelScope)
}

private fun onClickCheckedFilter(): Flow<PagingData<ItemEntity>> {
    return Pager(
        config = BasePagingSource.getConfig(),
        remoteMediator = RemoteMediator(checkedIds, cacheDatabase, client)
    ) {
        cacheDatabase.itemDao.getPagingSource(type, checkedIds)
    }.flow
}
```

Comment: Not positive, but try replacing `flatMapMerge` with `flatMapLatest`. That might not resolve your issue, but you need to make that change regardless. Otherwise, your previous queries and filters will still be running concurrently with the new ones and merged together (interleaved). You need to be dropping/cancelling any previous queries/filters as new ones arrive.

Comment: @Tenfour04 it works with `flatMapLatest` for `itemsFlow` and `collectLatest` on fragment side